# How to fix Loading a DLL

Tags: c++, dll

dll is not loading, i am suspecting there is a problem with the typecasting.

I typecasted to LPCWSTR, but it is failing while loading, if am giving the path directly its loading that is working fine. But its not taking strFile path.

```
HINSTANCE initH2oLibFilename(LPCSTR strFile, std::ostream& os)
{

HINSTANCE lib = LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)strFile);
    if(!lib)
    {
        os << "Error loading \'" << strFile <<'\''<< std::endl;
        return NULL;
    }
}


HINSTANCE initH2oLibIF97(LPCSTR strPath, std::ostream& os)
{

    std::string strFile(strPath);
    strFile += "H2O32Bit.dll";
    return initH2oLibFilename(strFile.c_str(), os);
}
```

Comment: How does `strFile` looks like before `initH2oLibFilename`? What is the exact error message? Please post a [mvce](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). BTW. since you are using `LPCSTR` you could use [LoadLibraryA(strFile)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/libloaderapi/nf-libloaderapi-loadlibrarya) instead of `LoadLibrary((LPCWSTR)strFile)`....

Answer (score 1):

`CWSTR` - uses 2 bytes to each character  (`WCHAR`)

`CSTR` - uses 1 byte for character (`CHAR`)

By making the cast on the pointer, it will refer to the CSTR as CWSTR, this will result in a gibrish instead of the file path. You can try to print the result of `(LPCWSTR)strFile` to the console, it’ll show you what I mean.

You will actually need to convert the values and not just cast the pointers.

You will need to use the `mbstowcs_s` function to convert the values.

You can learn more about converting the types in [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/text/how-to-convert-between-various-string-types?view=vs-2019) article:

Additional you should never use a c-style cast in c++. Use the relevant cast or a combination eg. `static_cast`.

Comment: thanks for your answer,  i tried with your solution it is working fine.

Comment: In other branch without casting to strFile, directly they are loading LoadLibrary(strFile);, and in project properties character set is setted to multibyte character set and useof MFC--> use standard windows libraries, it is working fine, but in failure case if am doing the above changes still it is not working. Getting 35 errors.

Comment: Errors: 1> Error 181 error LNK1104: cannot open file 'D:\Krawal\Devpt_branch\20433-21701-KM GUI Extraction\KalculationShadows\Debug\AggregatDTTrommel.obj' D:\Krawal\Devpt_branch\20433-21701-KM GUI Extraction\ExeStub\LINK ExeStub.                    can anyone please help why it is not compiling if i changed to mulit-byte character set   and why it is working with the old branch.?

Comment: This question is not related to this thread.
I suggest you will add a new question regarding your new issue.